# How to access/select nested data frame column with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  dplyr::select(Species, Petal.Width) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

Then I group by `Species` to get **[mean_se](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/mean_se.html)** with the following line of code:

```
df <- iris %>% 
  dplyr::select(Species, Petal.Width) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(ms = mean_se(Petal.Width))
```

It looks like this:

```
 df
# A tibble: 150 x 3
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Species Petal.Width  ms$y $ymin $ymax
   <fct>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
 2 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
 3 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
 4 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
 5 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
 6 setosa          0.4 0.246 0.231 0.261
 7 setosa          0.3 0.246 0.231 0.261
 8 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
 9 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
10 setosa          0.1 0.246 0.231 0.261
```

However when I want to select `ms$y` and `$ymax` column, like this

```
> df %>% dplyr::select(Species, ms$y, $ymax)
Error: unexpected '$' in "df %>% dplyr::select(Species, ms$y, $"
```

It fails. What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets stored as a nested dataframe. You can convert it to normal dataframe as :

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  select(Species, Petal.Width) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(ms = mean_se(Petal.Width)) %>%
  ungroup -> tmp

df <- bind_cols(tmp %>% select(-ms), tmp$ms) 
df

# A tibble: 150 x 5
#   Species Petal.Width     y  ymin  ymax
#   <fct>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
# 2 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
# 3 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
# 4 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
# 5 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
# 6 setosa          0.4 0.246 0.231 0.261
# 7 setosa          0.3 0.246 0.231 0.261
# 8 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
# 9 setosa          0.2 0.246 0.231 0.261
#10 setosa          0.1 0.246 0.231 0.261
# … with 140 more rows
```

Select the columns you need.

```
df %>% select(Species, y, ymax)

# A tibble: 150 x 3
#   Species     y  ymax
#   <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 setosa  0.246 0.261
# 2 setosa  0.246 0.261
# 3 setosa  0.246 0.261
# 4 setosa  0.246 0.261
# 5 setosa  0.246 0.261
# 6 setosa  0.246 0.261
# 7 setosa  0.246 0.261
# 8 setosa  0.246 0.261
# 9 setosa  0.246 0.261
#10 setosa  0.246 0.261
# … with 140 more rows
```

---

Another way without creating temporary variable `tmp` would be :

```
iris %>% 
  select(Species, Petal.Width) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(ms = list(mean_se(Petal.Width))) %>%
  unnest(ms) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to by pas `tmp` step?

Comment: Yes, you can store the output in a `list` and `unnest`. See the updated answer.